# How can I create a new app version only for recent devices?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

Can I create a new version of my app compatible only with iOS 13+ devices, while keeping the old version of my app available for older devices (such as the iPhone 6) ?

Thanks!

Comment: Simply update your app's deployment target to iOS 13.

Comment: @rmaddy I believe that will allow existing users to keep their version, but new users with old devices won't be able to download the app at all, correct? (I don't think it's possible to have multiple versions of an app available on App Store, which is what I think is being asked here.)

Comment: @RobNapier Maybe you're right. I thought the OP just wanted existing users to still have access to the older version of the app. Otherwise the question doesn't make much sense since an app can support both older and newer versions of iOS. No need for separate apps.

Comment: Yeah, but it'd often be a lot more convenient if you could just leave version 1 out there for users of older devices. This is really common in desktop software. Maintaining backward compatibility with ongoing development is a pain, but it's frustrating to cut off users if you don't have to.